# How to set absolute position for the header of mat-table?

Tags: css, angular-material-6

How to set the header position fixed, like:

```
.mat-header-row {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 60px;
}
```

But then I use it, my styles are crash, all header values `ID` and `Registered` merge in a single word without indentation.

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort aria-label="Elements" class="main-table">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="ip">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"><h4>{{item.ip}}</h4></mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="regDate">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Registered</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.regDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

How to set a fixed position for the header and save indentation?

Comment: Do you have any Fiddle link to this to see the working page.

Comment: @Manjuboyz unfortunately no. This huge enterprise app. Here I post the common example for a demo of problem.